# Anyone have any examples of how to use the 'click script' input for ae3e Plotly panel plugin for Grafana?

Tags: onclick, plotly, grafana

I am using Grafana v10.0.0 and the ae3e Plotly plugin v0.5.0.

From what I have been able to determine from playing around with it, the click script input area of the plugin is essentially a way to provide the code that one would put in the 'script' property of a 'click' event in a plotly layout if one were using Plotly without Grafana. The input area provides an object named 'data' which contains information about the click, x and y coords, etc, so it seems the intent of this is to do things based on where the user clicks the plot. But for the life of me I can't figure out how to affect the plot area in any way from this click script. The click script input area has no access to the plotly data, layout, or config definitions, so I can't figure out how to alter any of those. The single line example click script that initializes when you install the plugin tries to use `window.updateVariables({query:{'var-project':'test'}, partial: true})` to do something unclear, but the plugin just throws an error to the console saying `window.updateVariables`is not a function. I'm really at a loss. Anyone know how this works and can give me an example of doing something useful with the click script feature of this plugin?

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:** Found a workaround... update the "search" component of the url at window.location.search with clicked data.

I haven't be able to get the *window.updatevariables* function to work like the default you mention.  However, I did find a workaround by inspecting the window object in the browser console.  Clicked information comes in with the *data* object.  Then you want to manipulate window.location.search to get the Grafana response you want.

The downside is that the whole page refreshes after a click so it's not the best user experience but it does provide the callback functionality I think you are looking for.

Here's a code snippet I got working with a plotly sunburst chart.

```
console.log(data);
// window.updateVariables({query:{'var-project':'test'}, partial: true})

clickedNode = data.points[0].label
entryNode = data.points[0].entry
console.log(clickedNode)
console.log(entryNode)

newTarget = 'var-project=' + clickedNode
console.log("newTarget: " + newTarget)

console.log(window.location)
console.log(window.location.origin)
console.log(window.location.pathname)
console.log(window.location.search)
search=window.location.search
searchTerms=search.split('&')
console.log(searchTerms)
//check if the variable query param is already in the search url
target=-1
for (i in searchTerms) {
  console.log(i)
  console.log(searchTerms[i]);
  if (searchTerms[i].includes('project')){
    target=i;
  }
}
//replace or add variable param to the search url
if (target==-1) {
  console.log("appending search term")
  window.location.search+='&'+newTarget
}
else {
  console.log("replacing search term")
  console.log(searchTerms[target])
  oldTarget=searchTerms[target]
  console.log(window.location.search.replace(oldTarget,newTarget))
  window.location.search=window.location.search.replace(oldTarget,newTarget)
}
```

Comment: I wish there was a more graceful interface to avoid the clunky refresh.  Anyone else know how to get the intended "updatevariables"-like function to work with this Plotly plugin for Grafana?